# Is this loop behavior possible in Swiper?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Let's say we have the following [swiper](https://swiperjs.com/api/) slideshow:

- Number of slides: 7
- Slides per group: 3
- Clicked with buttons to move across pages:

By default, the slider will show the first group (1, 2, 3)

`[1 2 3] 4 5 6 7`

If clicked the right arrow button, it will go to the 2nd page:

`1 2 3 [4 5 6] 7`

The next one will show only one

`1 2 3 4 5 6 [7 _ _]`

And the next time we press the right arrow button will loop to the first page

`[1 2 3] 4 5 6 7`

Instead of this behavior, **I want the following one**:

The last page should show the following elements without blank spaces:

`1 2 3 4 [5 6 7]`

And then keep the next one will be again the first page

If, looping back from the last page (clicking the left arrow button), the behavior should be like this:

`1 2 3 4 [5 6 7]` > `1 [2 3 4] 5 6 7` > `[1 2 3] 4 5 6 7`

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Add related codes that you have tried.

Comment: I think this is not possible (By swiper API) - This is more an issue for GitHub-issue (For now "even - slidesPerGroup" put space for "un-even number of slides"). Its make sense - no way to a group of 3 for 7 items without [remainde] ). For specific case - you can use custom code (mySwiper.slideTo()) - or if "slide index = 1" do something

Comment: @EzraSiton yeah I started creating an issue in github but, there in the project is written to use stackoverflow so... ^^; - anyways, as I thought, there's no "easy way" to do this and will require pretty much custom code like you said. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, by default this behavior is not possible so I (my team) added some custom logic to achieve it:

I will post just some code, omitting the details. Also note that I'm using it with React and TypeScript

`progressMode` needs to be `'freescroll'`

```
public slideTimes = (times: number, direction: 'right' | 'left') => {
  const swiper = this.swiperRef.current && this.swiperRef.current.swiper;
  if (!swiper) return null;
  swiper.loopFix();
  swiper._clientLeft = swiper.$wrapperEl[0].clientLeft;
  return direction === 'right'
    ? swiper.slideTo(swiper.activeIndex + times)
    : swiper.slideTo(swiper.activeIndex - times);
};

protected slideNext = () => {
  if (!this.slideShowRef.current) {
    return;
  }
  const { currentPage } = this.state;
  const { services } = this.props;

  let nextPage = currentPage + 1;
  if (nextPage > Math.ceil(services.length / SLIDES_PER_PAGE)) {
    nextPage = 1;
  }
  this.setState({ currentPage: nextPage, swipping: true }, () => {
    const remainingServicesLastPage = services.length % SLIDES_PER_PAGE;
    if (
      remainingServicesLastPage !== 0 &&
      nextPage === Math.ceil(services.length / SLIDES_PER_PAGE)
    ) {
      return this.slideShowRef.current.slideTimes(remainingServicesLastPage, 'right');
    }
    return this.slideShowRef.current.slideTimes(SLIDES_PER_PAGE, 'right');
  });
};

protected slidePrev = () => {
  if (!this.slideShowRef.current) {
    return;
  }
  const { currentPage } = this.state;
  const { services } = this.props;

  let prevPage = currentPage - 1;
  if (prevPage < 1) {
    prevPage = Math.ceil(services.length / SLIDES_PER_PAGE);
  }
  this.setState({ currentPage: prevPage, swipping: true }, () => {
    const remainingServicesLastPage = services.length % SLIDES_PER_PAGE;
    if (
      remainingServicesLastPage !== 0 &&
      prevPage === Math.ceil(services.length / SLIDES_PER_PAGE) - 1
    ) {
      return this.slideShowRef.current.slideTimes(remainingServicesLastPage, 'left');
    }
    return this.slideShowRef.current.slideTimes(SLIDES_PER_PAGE, 'left');
  });
};
```